# Raspberry Pi not showing on network

Tags: raspbian, openelec, connection, samba, networking

I bought two Raspberry Pi 2 Bs, one to run kodi and the other to running Raspbian and is using Samba server. I had set up both up last night with the one running kodi getting files from the other Raspberry Pi, the Samba server was showing in my network on all of my computers.

Woke up to today, Kodi is still running fine and can still access files from the other Raspberry Pi, However the Raspberry Pi is not showing on my network for my computers so I cannot access files from there.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can access files from the Raspberry Pi on my computer.

This is what I have at the bottom of `smb.conf`:

```
[Shared]
comment = TV Folder
path = /mnt/usbstorage/
create mask = 0755
directory mask = 0755
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
force user = pi
force user = root
only guest = no
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume samba has crashed (since you say kodi can still see that Pi, the Ethernet stack must still be running on it) == so best I can suggest is use putty on the PC to link to the samba Pi and restart samba (or just issue a reboot)

The Pi has an internal 'watch dog' timer that can be used to 'trigger' (issue an interrupt) if it's not 'restarted' at regular intervals .. so you run a 'check' script that uses samba for some simple function (eg write to a log file) - if that fails & it locks up, the 'watch dog' will time-out and trigger and you can have that reboot the Pi.

NB. FYI in the 'old days' of computing, it was a well known fact that one way to 'improve' the 'reliability' of your corporate network was to have all your servers reboot everyday at midnight - if writing a 'self check' task is too much of a pain, just run a cron job to reboot at 3am (or whatever time of night you stop using it)